# Is 'lord' capitalized after a possessive pronoun?

Tags: capitalization

Is 'lord' capitalized after a possessive pronoun?

Example:

O our lord! / O our Lord!

Comment: 'Lord' is always capitalized when writing about the Christian god, after a preposition or not.

Comment: @Mitch No it's not. Lots of Christians wouldn't capitalise it, and I'm sure there would even be some published Bibles which don't!

Comment: @curiousdannii Oh. I was being to generalized. Isn't it the case that you capitalize it when referring to the Christian God? 'Our Lord', 'the Lord'?

Comment: Mitch is spot on. For reasons beyond the scope of ELU, the Christian community considers Lord a name of God, so *our Lord* becomes the equivalent to people in a family referring to a member of the family as *our Fred*.

Comment: @Mitch and ScotM That's a matter of personal preference. Most would, but *always* is overstating it.

Comment: @curiousdannii Non-believers probably wouldn't refer to the Abrahamic god as *our Lord* or *the Lord* to begin with, and in set phrases like *thank the Lord* that have largely lost their religious significance, I'd still advise capitalization lest one be mistaken for thanking a human lord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you are directly addressing someone by his or her title, it is capitalized --in this case I would capitalize the entire phrase "Our Lord", since it's being used to directly address the subject (*references:* [1](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000049.htm) [2](http://www.towson.edu/ows/capitalization_rules.htm) [3](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp)).  You would also capitalize if the title was being used as a proper name, or if it was attached directly to a proper name (*i.e.* "Be merciful, *Lord Jesus*").

Complicating things a bit is the fact that many religious people [capitalize references to God](http://parablemania.ektopos.com/archives/2004/06/divine_capitali.html) even in the case that they wouldn't usually be capitalized, as in "we bless His holy name" or even "we bless His Holy Name."   This is done as an extra gesture of respect, but is not considered to align with standard English usage.

In this case, however, both approaches agree on capitalization.

Comment: This is true enough, Chris, but it would probably be good to cite some authoritative source.

Comment: @ScotM Good call, I corrected an inaccuracy after checking some sources.